# Numerical Error in simple CUDA code

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpu, numerical

I just started experimenting cuda with the following cude

```
#include "macro.hpp"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

//#define double float
//#define double int

int RandomNumber(){return static_cast<double>(rand() % 1000);}

__global__ void sum3(double const* a,
             double const* b,
             double const* c,
             double * result, 
             unsigned const* n)
{    
   unsigned i = blockIdx.x;
   while(i < (*n))
{
  result[i] = (a[i] + b[i] + c[i]);
}
};


int main()
{

  static unsigned size = 1e2;
  srand(0);
  double* a = new double[size];
  double* b = new double[size];
  double* c = new double[size];
  double* result = new double[size];

  std::generate(a, a+size, RandomNumber);
  std::generate(b, b+size, RandomNumber);
  std::generate(c, c+size, RandomNumber);

  double* ad, *bd,* cd;
  double* resultd;

  unsigned * sized;
  std::cout << cudaMalloc((void**) &ad, size*sizeof(double)) << std::endl;
  std::cout << cudaMalloc((void**) &bd, size*sizeof(double)) << std::endl;
  std::cout << cudaMalloc((void**) &cd, size*sizeof(double)) << std::endl;
  std::cout << cudaMalloc((void**) &resultd, size*sizeof(double)) << std::endl;
  std::cout << cudaMalloc((void**) &sized, sizeof(unsigned)) << std::endl;

  cudaMemcpy((void**) &sized, &size, sizeof(unsigned), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  //  print_array(a, size);
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
      cudaMemcpy(ad, a, size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      cudaMemcpy(bd, b, size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      cudaMemcpy(cd, c, size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);      
      sum3<<<size, 1>>>(ad, bd, cd, resultd, sized);
      cudaMemcpy(result, resultd, size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    }

#ifdef PRINT
  for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
      std::cout << a[i] << ", "<< b[i] <<"," << c[i] << "," << result[i]<< std::endl;
    }
#endif

  cudaFree(ad);
  cudaFree(bd);
  cudaFree(cd);
  cudaFree(resultd);

  delete[] a;
  delete[] b;
  delete[] c;
  delete[] result;

  return 0;
}
```

Compile this on mac book pro without any problem. However when I try to run this I get

```
930, 22,538,899
691, 832,205,23
415, 655,148,120
872, 876,481,985
761, 909,583,619
841, 104,466,917
610, 635,911,52
//more useless numbers
```

I have compared my samples with the one in Cuda By Example and I dont see any major difference except type. Any pointer on this problem is appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect this line to do? std::generate(a, a+size, RandomNumber);  
It would expect that a+size is wrong, as adding an array pointer to a number is usually wrong, as you are going past the end of the array.

Comment: doesnt *(a+size) give the address space right after the element a[size-1]?

Comment: @James: Going one past the array is fine and quite common. @leon: Your pointer arithmetic is fine. Though you really need to use Scope-bound Resource Management concepts (also known as RAII.) Use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays, *always*. And you should probably wrap the CUDA memory into a container as well. If you're in a position to have to free something, you've done it wrong. It should happen automatically.

Comment: @Gman In ideal world, all the code above should all be in straight C will `Malloc()` and `Free`. I am using `new` because it is few char less than `malloc()` in the prototype:)

Comment: @leon: I'm not sure I follow. You use a `std::vector`, it's safer and easier. What do you lose by using it? It takes 2 minutes to make basic a wrapper around some memory.

Comment: @Gman Vector is not raw array afterall. This is a prototype so I want to model it as close to C as possible so I can switch to C very easily later. For example, if I use Vector, then I have to pass &(a[0]) instead of a into cudaMemcpy because not all c++ std::vector name points to the first element of the array.

Comment: @leon: Yes, `&a[0]` or `&a.front()` is quite common. Switching to C isn't going to be any harder, but your C++ will sure be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(i < (*n))
{
  result[i] = (a[i] + b[i] + c[i]);
}
```

is wrong (infinite)

this is wrong

```
cudaMemcpy((void**) &sized, &size, sizeof(unsigned), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

`&sized` is address of pointer variable, not pointer value

Single number can be passed to device on the stack, so use

```
unsigned size
```

check return status of your cuda functions, http://www.drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/207603131

Comment: @leon.  sorry, I misunderstood your code before, see my update

Comment: I just realised that it should an `if` instead of `while` :)

Answer (score -1):

you wrote:

```
double* a = new double[size];
```

so, "a" is a pointer to an array of doubles, then you say

```
  std::generate(a, a+size, RandomNumber);
  std::generate(b, b+size, RandomNumber);
  std::generate(c, c+size, RandomNumber);
```

which is wrong, you should say

```
  std::generate(*a, (*a)+size, RandomNumber);
  std::generate(*b, (*b)+size, RandomNumber);
  std::generate(*c, (*c)+size, RandomNumber);
```

Would be easier to help you if you state what do you want your program to do.

Also, you put

```
 unsigned * sized;
 std::cout << cudaMalloc((void**) &ad, size*sizeof(double)) << std::endl;
```

but you could do

```
 unsigned * sized;
 std::cout << cudaMalloc((void*) ad, size*sizeof(double)) << std::endl;
```

depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: In C/C++ the name `a` in `a[]` is the pointer that points to the first element of the array, and not pointing to an array of double. 

Second, `std::generate` takes pointer(iterator) that points to the beginning of the range and the memory address right after the last element in the range. `(*a)+size` = a[0]+size does not make sense for the generate argument. 

lastly , `cudaMalloc()` takes pointer of pointer so I am passing `&ad`. `(void**) &ad` is not the same as `(void*)ad`. What is the same is `*&ad` and `ad` but this is not what I am doing.